# how to read a js file and parse the default export module into JSON using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

In Node.js, I want to be able to read a sample.js file containing ES Module syntax and parse the default export.

**sample.js**

```js
import foo from "foo";

const bar = [
  {
    name: "Homer",
  },
  {
    name: "Marge",
  },
  {
    name: "Bart",
  },
  {
    name: "Lisa",
  },
  {
    name: "Maggie",
  },
];

export const addOne = (num) => num + 1;

export default bar;
```

So far, my node.js script is simply reading the file contents and outputting it to console.log. Here is my node.js script:

**index.js**

```js
const fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile("./sample.js", "utf8", (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(data);
  // how can I parse the default export from data?
});
```

If I could somehow obtain the string `[{"name":"Homer"},{"name":"Marge"},{"name":"Bart"},{"name":"Lisa"},{"name":"Maggie"}]` after reading the file, then I could simply perform `JSON.parse` and get the data that I need. But this doesn't seem like a trivial task. How could I read raw js file and parse the default export into JSON?

Comment: Why don't you just actually import the file with `require()` or `import` and then directly access the exported value?

Comment: thanks. i had a feeling i was doing something weird. I ended up using `require('sample').default`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply

```
import data from './sample.js';

console.log(data);
```

Also, make sure that in `package.json` you have this line: `"type": "module"`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. unfortunately, I'm unable to follow your suggestion because some of my node modules don't work well that way. However, I could use `esm` npm package and be able to use `import` in my node.js script

Answer (score 0):

If there's a reason why you can't do what other commenters have suggested, you could use an ast generator like babel or acorn. https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/b6f15acb88afbf6b6ee1426e4d44fd15/a5e2721f04af041fc704e8d4fa9cefe77e9b872a shows acorn's parsing of the code. You can search through the tree for the value you are looking for, pull out the substring.

Comment: i was thinking about this as well, but glad i don't have to do this since I can simply `require` or `import` :)